# SUMPRODUCT doesn't recognise OFFSET array

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm working through an Excel exercise in which I need to `SUMPRODUCT` two tables of related values. Unfortunately, I can't be sure the tables will always be ordered identically.

To get around this, I have looked up their values into a new third table; this works, however I'm now looking for a way to do it in one cell.

My code is currently

```
SUMPRODUCT(Resources_Used18[In House],OFFSET(Rate_comparison[Role],MATCH(Resources_Used18[Role],Rate_comparison[Role],0)-1,1))
```

For some reason however this doesn't seem to work and only ever returns zeros. The `OFFSET(,MATCH())` is meant to reconstruct the second data array, this appears to work and when I test it with `F9` it produces the array I'm expecting.

Additionally when I manually enter the array, it provides the correct answer.

So I think the error must be with `SUMPRODUCT` failing to recognise it as an array.

Where is the error and how can I correct my formula? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Actually I need to correct myself, `OFFSET` produce the correct array when run in a cell of its however after I run the cell if I don't ctrl-shift-enter then produces an array of errors.
EDIT:EDIT: An example of the sort of data I'm looking is this,

### Rate_comparison

```
| Role | Rate |
|------|------|
| 1    | 50   |
| 2    | 100  |
| 3    | 150  |
| 4    | 200  |
| 5    | 250  |
| 6    | 300  |
| 7    | 350  |
| 8    | 400  |
| 9    | 450  |
```

And

### Resources_Used18

```
| Role | In house |
|------|----------|
| 9    | 23       |
| 8    | 24       |
| 4    | 25       |
| 3    | 26       |
| 1    | 27       |
| 7    | 28       |
| 6    | 29       |
| 5    | 30       |
| 2    | 31       |
```

Comment: If you provide a link to a sample worksheet that demonstrates the problem, it will be much easier to help you debug things.

Comment: Unfortunately the Worksheet is part of an exercise. I have permission to ask as the teacher can't find a way however the sheets them selves don't belong to me.

Comment: Then create a similar worksheet that demonstrates the problem, and post that.

Comment: Best way is to upload the file to some public file sharing site **that does not require registration to download from** such as Dropbox, or possibly OneDrive, and then post a link here.  If the data is small, you might try the [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  That would only show the data, so be sure the applicable formulas are clear in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue before, and cannot explain it.  However, if you enclose the `OFFSET` function inside the `N` function, the actual values will be returned.

I did not check to see if the result (59,300) is correct however.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Resources_Used18[ [ In house ] ],N(OFFSET(Rate_Comparison[ [ Role ] ],MATCH(Resources_Used18[ [ Role ] ],Rate_Comparison[ [ Role ] ],0)-1,1)))
```

According to [Tushar Metar](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/array_formulas.htm#_ftn3), The OFFSET function, when used with an array as the 2nd or 3rd argument, returns an undocumented data structure that is understood only by Excel.  The N function converts the data from the internal structure into one that can be displayed or used for further analysis.  Laurent Longre deserves the credit for discovering this capability of the N function.

Comment: @J.Blake One might think so, but if you examine the output of the offset function, they appear to be numeric. `=OFFSET(Resources_Used18[[ Role ]],MATCH(Rate_Comparison[[ Role ]],Resources_Used18[[ Role ]],0),1,1,1)` **-->**  `{28;0;27;26;31;30;29;25;24}`

Comment: @J.Blake I have edited my answer to show a possible explanation of the need for the `N()` function